# como fazer um substring em um int no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

tenho o seguinte código:

```
$chk_selectes = $_REQUEST['chk_selectes'];
```

ele recebe via REQUEST uma variável com este valor: 000 ou 001 ou 011 ou 111.

preciso verificar cada um destes elementos então usei:

```
$um = substr("$_REQUEST['chk_selectes']", 0,1);
$dois = substr("$_REQUEST['chk_selectes']", 1,1);
$tres= substr("$_REQUEST['chk_selectes']", 2,1);
```

mas como o valor de chk_selectes é 000 e isso é um int esta dando erro.

ja tentei isso:

```
$chk_selectes = (string) $_REQUEST['chk_selectes'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você recupera qualquer variável que seja do tipo *integer*, automaticamente você está transformando `001` em `1`. Como o seu padrão possui apenas 3 dígitos numéricos você pode usar [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
sprintf('%03d', 001);
```

No seu código:

```
$chk_selectes = sprintf('%03d', $_REQUEST['chk_selectes']);

$um = substr($chk_selectes, 0,1);
$dois = substr($chk_selectes, 1,1);
$tres= substr($chk_selectes, 2,1);
```

Você pode ver funcionando [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c2810559a23e4aa490075aa3ff92df3b1e970fc).

Referências:

- [How to keep leading zeros in PHP integer [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148486/how-to-keep-leading-zeros-in-php-integer)
- [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699980/2456028)

Comment: Só um adendo: tenha certeza que o valor do request é um *integer*. Quando testei com `011` ele foi tratado como um octadecimal, se transformando em `9`, o que resultou em `009`. Veja [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38673589/2456028) para maiores detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

`000`, `001` não é int e com certeza `$_REQUEST['chk_selectes']` não traz valores `int`

Se o front-end no form esta de fato enviando exatamente `000`, então vai chegar `000`, como string, logo se `000` virou `0` é porque houve alguma coisa no meio disto, talvez no momento de enviar o FORM, Ajax, alguma função que afete toda a `$_REQUEST`.

Parece também que você esta tentando extrair os dados, se tem certeza que sempre será algo com 3 dígitos então poderia usar `[...]` na string ao invés de usar `substr`

> Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Assim com certeza é mais simples:

```
$um = $chk_selectes[0];
$dois = $chk_selectes[1];
$tres = $chk_selectes[2];

var_dump($um, $dois, $tres);
```

IDEONE: https://ideone.com/TMryqi

Eu creio que seria mais interessante `substr` para quando necessitar de um "range" maior ou diferente da string.

Comment: show! realmente assim fica mais simples que com substring rs

Comment: @JulioHenrique não esqueça do problema inicial `sprintf` pode ter lhe resolvido o problema ali, mas com certeza não tem sentido $_REQUEST ter lhe trazido INT. Mesmo que envie o numero 1 via form vai chegar como string no _REQUEST. O problema é outra coisa.